# Cannot get Child Element Values in the XML

Tags: php, xml, web-services, domdocument

I get following response from a Web Service. I need to get the values inside the the dtAccData (`FULL_NAME`, `GLOBAL_ID`)

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <strGetCustomerValidationResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
    <strGetCustomerValidationResult>21^Please complete your pending form^150675^1</strGetCustomerValidationResult>
    <dtAccData>
      <xs:schema id="NewDataSet" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
        <xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:MainDataTable="Table" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xs:element name="Table">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="FULL_NAME" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="GLOBAL_ID" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
              </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
          </xs:choice>
        </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:schema>
      <diffgr:diffgram xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1">
        <NewDataSet xmlns="">
          <Table diffgr:id="Table1" msdata:rowOrder="0">
            <FULL_NAME>TEST39</FULL_NAME>
            <GLOBAL_ID>37405-9879863-7</GLOBAL_ID>
          </Table>
        </NewDataSet>
      </diffgr:diffgram>
    </dtAccData>
  </strGetCustomerValidationResponse>
</soap:Envelope>
```

If I load to simple XML object and dump, I do not see any values inside dtAccData. I only get below.

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xml_tring);
var_dump($xml);
```

I get

```
GetCustomerValidationResponse"]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#2 (2) { ["strGetCustomerValidationResult"]=> string(45) "21^Please complete your pending form^630160^1" ["dtAccData"]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#3 (0) { } } }
```

What should I do.

Comment: Why are you not using the SOAP extension?

Comment: @ThW I did not know that it is possible to parse XML with SOAP extension. Can you post a sample code.

Comment: You example is not just XML, it is SOAP. SOAP uses XML as a base format/syntax. PHP has an extension for that: http://www.php.net/soap

Comment: @ThW Yes, I know, but SOAP extension does not have any method to parse the result XML received.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here we are using `DOMDocument` for extracting `textContent` inside an element.

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/789061)

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$string='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <strGetCustomerValidationResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
    <strGetCustomerValidationResult>21^Please complete your pending form^150675^1</strGetCustomerValidationResult>
    <dtAccData>
      <xs:schema id="NewDataSet" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
        <xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:MainDataTable="Table" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xs:element name="Table">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="FULL_NAME" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="GLOBAL_ID" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
              </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
          </xs:choice>
        </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:schema>
      <diffgr:diffgram xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1">
        <NewDataSet xmlns="">
          <Table diffgr:id="Table1" msdata:rowOrder="0">
            <FULL_NAME>TEST39</FULL_NAME>
            <GLOBAL_ID>37405-9879863-7</GLOBAL_ID>
          </Table>
        </NewDataSet>
      </diffgr:diffgram>
    </dtAccData>
  </strGetCustomerValidationResponse>
</soap:Envelope>';
$domDocument= new DOMDocument();
$domDocument->loadXML($string);
echo $FULL_NAME=$domDocument->getElementsByTagName("FULL_NAME")->item(0)->textContent;
echo PHP_EOL;
echo $GLOBAL_ID=$domDocument->getElementsByTagName("GLOBAL_ID")->item(0)->textContent;
```

**Output:**

`TEST39
37405-9879863-7`

If your `XML` response contains no. of these tags from which you want to extract information. You can use this code, for getting `multiple occurences`

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/789062) `for multiple occurences`

```
<?php

$domDocument= new DOMDocument();
$domDocument->loadXML($string);
$result=array();
foreach($domDocument->getElementsByTagName("FULL_NAME") as $fullnameElement)
{
    $result["FULL_NAME"][]=$fullnameElement->textContent;
}
foreach($domDocument->getElementsByTagName("GLOBAL_ID") as $fullnameElement)
{
    $result["GLOBAL_ID"][]=$fullnameElement->textContent;
}
print_r($result);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [FULL_NAME] => Array
        (
            [0] => TEST39
        )

    [GLOBAL_ID] => Array
        (
            [0] => 37405-9879863-7
        )

)
```

Comment: This works like a charm for me because, I know all the elements and number of occurrence of each element. Thanks Sahil. If you know how should we do it when we have a repeating structure, please share that too. Anyway thanks a lot.

Comment: @KasunRajapaksha I have updated my post you can check it.  welcome.... :)

Comment: Superb Sahil. Thanks a lot.